# Document.ready() failing on popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am using ASP.Net and jQuery/jQuery UI and I am trying to use the datepicker control. It works fine on every page, except when I have to use the popup (to add new data into the database and then i refresh the current page to reflect the new data being entered). It seems that document.ready() is failing when I use the popup. I can invoke the datepicker control manually with adding a click event to fire off the showcalendar function, however I want to try and make it work. Does anyone have any ideas of why a popup would fail document.ready() ?

Thanks!

Code in UserInterfaces.js Script File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".calendarTrigger").datepicker({showOn:'focus', showAnim: 'fadeIn', changeMonth: true, showOn:'both', buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1950:2010'});

});
```

Code Calling Popup Functionality:

```
<a href="#" onclick='javascript:openWindow("/modules/prh/AI.aspx","PH","480","650","","");'
```

Code For Modal Popup That we use:

```
function openWindow(url,name,height,width,left,top)
{
if(!width) {width = 625};
if(!height){height = 625}; 
if(!left) {left = 60};
if(!top){top = 60};    
if (!name) {name='mk'};

name = name.replace(" ","");

if ((window.showModalDialog) && (navigator.appName!="Microsoft Internet Explorer"))
{
        grayOut(true);

        newWindow = window.showModalDialog(url,"name","dialogWidth: " + width + "px;dialogHeight:  " + height + "px;resizable: 1;status: 0;scrollbars: 1;dialogLeft: " + left +"px;dialogTop: " + top + "px");

        if (newWindow)
            newWindow.focus();

        grayOut(false);

}
else
{
    newWindow = window.open(url,name,'width=' + width + ',height='+ height + 
    ',resizable=1,status=0,scrollbars=1,left=' + left +',top=' + top);

    if (newWindow)
        newWindow.focus();
    else 
        window.Name.focus();

 }
}

function grayOut(vis, options) {
// Pass true to gray out screen, false to ungray
// options are optional.  This is a JSON object with the following (optional) properties
// opacity:0-100         // Lower number = less grayout higher = more of a blackout 
// zindex: #             // HTML elements with a higher zindex appear on top of the gray out
// bgcolor: (#xxxxxx)    // Standard RGB Hex color code
// grayOut(true, {'zindex':'50', 'bgcolor':'#0000FF', 'opacity':'70'});
// Because options is JSON opacity/zindex/bgcolor are all optional and can appear
// in any order.  Pass only the properties you need to set.
var options = options || {}; 
var zindex = options.zindex || 50;
var opacity = options.opacity || 70;
var opaque = (opacity / 100);
var bgcolor = options.bgcolor || '#000000';
var dark=document.getElementById('darkenScreenObject');
    var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
if (!dark) 
{
    // The dark layer doesn't exist, it's never been created.  So we'll
    // create it here and apply some basic styles.
    // If you are getting errors in IE see: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/927917
    var tnode = document.createElement('div');           // Create the layer.
    tnode.style.position='absolute';                 // Position absolutely
    tnode.style.top='0px';                           // In the top
    tnode.style.left='0px';                          // Left corner of the page
    tnode.style.overflow='hidden';                   // Try to avoid making scroll bars            
    tnode.style.display='none';                      // Start out Hidden
    tnode.id='darkenScreenObject';                   // Name it so we can find it later
    tbody.appendChild(tnode);                            // Add it to the web page
    dark=document.getElementById('darkenScreenObject');  // Get the object.
}


if (vis) 
{
    var pageWidth="100%";
    var pageHeight=getPageHeightWithScroll();
if (window.innerHeight>pageHeight)
    pageHeight = window.innerHeight;
pageHeight = pageHeight + "px";

    //set the shader to cover the entire page and make it visible.
    dark.style.opacity=opaque;                      
    dark.style.MozOpacity=opaque;                   
    dark.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')'; 
    dark.style.zIndex=zindex;        
    dark.style.backgroundColor=bgcolor;  
    dark.style.width= pageWidth;
    dark.style.height= pageHeight;
    dark.style.display='block';                          
} 
else 
{
    dark.style.display='none';
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see document.ready anywhere in your code...am I missing something?

Comment: @Seth - This .js file is included in the popup window in `/modules/prh/AI.aspx` ?

Comment: Yes it is included in the master page of the main page and then in the master page for the popup

Comment: @Seth - Stick an `alert('hey')` inside that document.ready, I think you'll see that it's firing.  Is the `class="calendarTrigger"` element present on load, or is it added later?

Comment: Alert Doesn't get fired, for some reason that popup just isn't set to the ready state. The Textbox with the class "calendarTrigger" is present at load.

Comment: @Seth - `$(document).ready()` doesn't mean "fire **if** ready", it means "fire **when** ready".  Can you load that window with firebug up and make sure no javascript errors are occuring in that window?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, it' was a javascript error that was only visible after stepping through 250+ lines of javascript code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the markup for your popup and do you have any other javascript that could possibly cause an error before datepicker fires inside the popup?

Comment: I have Firebugs jScript Debugger running and nothing breaks that I have been able to tell, just seems to hit the document.ready() for the jQuery Code and that comes back false or fails and skips over the datepicker initilization

Comment: There was an error in my HoverIntent, didn't catch it till now, this is the answer (sort of).